# Maximum of k real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis

Let $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_k$ are real numbers.

Prove that

$$\sum_{1 \leq m \leq k} a_{m} - \sum_{1 \leq m < n \leq k } \min (a_{m},a_{n}) +\sum_{1 \leq m < n <p \leq k } \min (a_{m},a_{n},a_{p})$$
$$ - \cdots \pm \min(a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{k}) = \max(a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{k}). $$

For example, if $k=3$, the given statement becomes

$a_{1} + a_{2} + a_{3} - \min(a_{1},a_{2}) - \min(a_{1},a_{3}) - \min(a_{2},a_{3}) + \min(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}) = \max(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3})$

which is easy to check.

For $k=4$, the given statement becomes

$a_{1} + a_{2} + a_{3} + a_{4} - \min(a_{1},a_{2}) - \min(a_{1},a_{3}) - \min(a_{1},a_{4}) - \min(a_{2},a_{3}) - \min(a_{2},a_{4}) - \min(a_{3},a_{4}) + \min(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}) + \min(a_{1},a_{2},a_{4}) + \min(a_{1},a_{3},a_{4}) + \min(a_{2},a_{3},a_{4}) - \min(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4})= \max(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4}).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: You can prove it by induction on $k$. Suppose that it’s true for some $k$, and let $a_1,\ldots,a_{k+1}$ be real numbers. Without loss of generality assume that $a_{k+1}=\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_{k+1}\}$. (You can always relabel the numbers if necessary.) Apply your induction hypothesis to $a_1,\ldots,a_k$. Then include $a_{m+1}$ in the lefthand side and see how each term is affected.

- You’ll add $a_{k+1}$ to the first summation.
- You’ll add $\sum_{1\le m\le k}a_m$ to the second summation.
- You’ll add $\sum_{1\le m<n\le k}\min\{a_m,a_n\}$ to the third summation.

So far the net change is

$$a_{k+1}-\sum_{1\le m\le k}a_m+\sum_{1\le m<n\le k}\min\{a_m,a_n\}\;,$$

and a pattern is emerging. Identify the pattern, prove that it’s really there, and show that in the end the net change is $a_{k+1}-\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$; that last step is where you use the induction hypothesis.